# File downloads in IE6

Tags: php, internet-explorer-6, download

I've come across a rather interesing (and frustrating) problem with IE6. We are serving up some server generated pdfs and then simply setting headers in PHP to force a browser download of the file. Works fine and all, except in IE6 but **only** if the windows user account is set to standard user (ie. not administrator).

Since this is for a corporate environment, of course all their accounts are setup this way. Weird thing is, that in the download dialog, the Content-Type is not recognized:

```
header( 'Pragma: public' );
header( 'Expires: 0' );
header( 'Cache-Control: must-revalidate, pre-check=0, post-check=0' );
header( 'Cache-Control: public' );
header( 'Content-Description: File Transfer' );
header( 'Content-Type: application/pdf' );
header( 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="xxx.pdf"' );
header( 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary' );
echo $content;
exit;
```

I also tried writing the file content to a temporary file first so I could also set the `Content-Length` in the header but that didn't help.

Comment: Sounds like a good excuse to deploy Firefox via Group Policy =)

Answer (score 4):

### These headers are bogus!

```
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
```

This header is copied from e-mail headers. It doesn't apply to HTTP simply because HTTP doesn't have any other mode of transfer than binary. Setting it makes as much sense as setting `X-Bits-Per-Byte: 8`.

```
Cache-control: pre-check=0, post-check=0
```

These non-standard values define when IE should check whether cached content is still fresh. `0` is the default, so setting it to `0` is waste of time. These directives apply only to cacheable content, and `Expires:0` and `must-revalidate` hint that you wanted to make it non-cacheable.

```
Content-Description: File Transfer
```

This is another e-mail copycat. *By design* this header *doesn't affect download in any way*. It's just informative free-form text. It's technically as useful as `X-Hi-Mom: I'm sending you a file!` header.

```
header( 'Cache-Control: must-revalidate, pre-check=0, post-check=0' );
header( 'Cache-Control: public' );
```

In PHP second line *completely overwrites* the first one. You seem to be stabbing in the dark.

### What really makes a difference

```
Content-Disposition: attachment
```

You don't have to insert filename there (you can use `mod_rewrite` or `index.php/fakefilename.doc` trick – it gives much better support for special characters and works in browsers that ignore the *optional* `Content-Disposition` header).

In IE it makes difference whether file is in cache or not ("Open" doens't work for non-cacheable files), and whether user has plug-in that claims to support type of file that IE detects.

To disable cache you only need `Cache-control:no-cache` (without 20 extra fake headers), and to make file cacheable you don't have to send anything.

**NB: PHP has horrible misfeature called `session.cache_limiter` which hopelessly screws up HTTP headers unlesss you set it to `none`.**

```
ini_set('session.cache_limiter','none'); // tell PHP to stop screwing up HTTP
```

Comment: On Kubuntu, the default for Apache/php5 sets `session.cache_limiter = nocache`.

Answer (score 3):

some versions of IE seem to take

```
header( 'Expires: 0' );
header( 'Cache-Control: must-revalidate, pre-check=0, post-check=0' );
```

way too seriously and remove the downloaded content before it's passed to the plugin to display it.

Remove these two and you should be fine.

And make sure you are not using any server-side GZIP compression when working with PDFs because some versions of Acrobat seem to struggle with this.

I know I'm vague here, but above tips are based on real-world experience I got using a web application serving dynamically built PDFs containing barcodes. I don't know what versions are affected, I only know that using the two "tricks" above made the support calls go away :p

Answer (score 1):

I have had the exact same problem about a year ago, and after much googling and research, my headers (from Java code) look for IE6 & PDFs like this:

```
    response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf "; name=" + file.getName());
    response.setContentType("application/pdf");
    response.setHeader("Last-Modified", getHeaderDate(file.getFile());
    response.setHeader("Content-Length", file.getLength());
```

Drop everything else.

There is apparently something a bit whacky with IE6, caching, forced downloading and plug-ins.  I hope this works for you...a small difference for me is that the request initially comes from a Flash swf file.  But that should not matter.

Answer (score 1):

I appreciate the time you guys spent on this post. I tried several combinations and finally got my symfony project to work. Here I post the solutions in case anyone will have the same problem:

```
public function download(sfResponse $response) {

        $response->clearHttpHeaders();
        $response->setHttpHeader('Pragma: public', true);
        $response->addCacheControlHttpHeader("Cache-control","private");        
        $response->setContentType('application/octet-stream', true);
        $response->setHttpHeader('Content-Length', filesize(sfConfig::get('sf_web_dir') .       sfConfig::get('app_paths_docPdf') . $this->getFilename()), true);
        $response->setHttpHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"". $this->getFilename() ."\"");
        $response->setHttpHeader('Content-Transfer-Encoding', 'binary', true);
        $response->setHttpHeader("Content-Description","File Transfer");
        $response->sendHttpHeaders();
        $response->setContent(readfile(sfConfig::get('sf_web_dir') . sfConfig::get('app_paths_docPdf') . $this->getFilename()));

        return sfView::NONE;
}
```

This works just fine for me in IE6,IE7, Chrome, Firefox.

Hope this will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

As pilif already mentions, make sure to turn off the server-side gzip compression. For me this has caused problems with PDF files (among other types) and for maybe-not-so-obscure reasons also with .zip files both under Internet Explorer and FireFox.

As far as I could tell, the last bit of the zip footer would get stripped (at least by FireFox) causing a corrupted format.

In PHP you can use the following code:

```
ini_set("zlib.output_compression",0);
```

Answer (score 0):

The following bit of Java code works for me (tested on Firefox 2 and 3, IE 6 and 7):

```
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + file.getName() + "\"");
response.setContentType(getServletContext().getMimeType(file.getName()));
response.setContentLength(file.length());
```

No other headers were necessary at all.
Also, I tested this code both with gzip compression on and off (using a separate servlet filter that does the compression). Doesn't make any difference (works without any problem in the four browsers I tested it on).
Plus, this works for other filetypes as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an additional parameter that the server won't read to the url it might help too.

http://www.mycom.com/services/pdf?action=blahblah&filename=pdf0001.pdf

I have run into cases where ie will be more likely to read the filename on the end of the url than any of the headers

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, but it might not be exactly related. My issue was that IE6 seems to have a problem with special characters (specifically slashes) in the file name. Removing these fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

**If you are using SSL:**

Make sure you do not include any cache control (or Pragma) headers.  There is a bug in IE6 which will prevent users from downloading files if cache control headers are used.  They will get an error message.

I pulled my hair out over this for 2 days, so hopefully this message helps someone.

Comment: This is the knowledge base article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323308/en-us - the header should be set with `header('Cache-Control: private');` in IE.

Answer (score 0):

simply switch to this content type and it will work, also be sure Pragma ist set to something NOT equal "no-cache"

```
header( 'Content-type: application/octet-stream'); # force download, no matter what mimetype
header( 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary' ); # is always ok, also for plain text
```