# When I export files with php/html my session data resets

Tags: php, html, csv, export, xls

I have a web-based system built with user login data based on session variables.

Sometimes when a user is logged in and tries to export tables to csv or xls the session data seems to wipe and the user is 'kicked out' of the system.

This is the header code I'm using to serve the file.

```
    header("Pragma: public");
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Type: application/download");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=file.xls");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary ");
```

If it helps it seems to be more prevalent on ie6. I was wondering if anyone has had similar issues.

This is the latest header I've tried. Still no luck. Also tested the exact same procedure in FF/Opera/Safari and they're fine.

```
header('Cache-Control: no-store, private, no-cache, must-revalidate');     // HTTP/1.1
    header('Cache-Control: pre-check=0, post-check=0, max-age=0, max-stale = 0', false);  // HTTP/1.1
    header('Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');                  // Date in the past  
    header('Expires: 0', false); 
    header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s') . ' GMT');
    header('Pragma: no-cache');
    header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=$fileName");
            header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary ");
```

Comment: the expires header should be in this format (yes GMT): Expires: Thu, 01 Dec 1994 16:00:00 GMT

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Pragma: public` header is completely inappropriate for logged-in users and isn't going to help anything.

I'm also a bit baffled as to why you're using so many `Content-Type` headers.  Choose one and one only.

Finally, those are the headers you're explicitly setting...  You don't have any calls to `session_destroy` or `setcookie` floating around do you?

Comment: Thanks for the response, no their definitely no calls to destroy the session, I'll give your suggestions a shot and see how it goes.

Comment: If the issue lies with serving publicly-cached pages to logged-in users, you may want to check-out answers on this other thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/making-sure-a-webpage-is-not-cached-across-all-browsers

Comment: Hmm that definitely doesn't work. Even when I remove most of the headers, we definitely don't have session_destory or setcookie being called. Is there any other calls the system could make to cause such issues? To elaborate if I open ie6, log in and press Export to Xls I'm kicked out. I re-login again and press export to Xls, the file is served perfectly fine.

Comment: What do you mean by 'kicked out?'  As you're using `Content-Disposition: attachment` the browser shouldn't even be refreshing the page - so could it be your next action that's logging you out, not the  download action?

Comment: By kicking out I mean all SESSION data is wiped and the user is forwarded to the front-page. I agree that because it's Content-Disposition: attachment the browser shouldn't refresh, but basically what occurs is:

1) Display headers
2) Generate a long string that stores the XLS
3) Pack it using this return pack("ss", 0x0A, 0x00); 
4) echo the xls out. 

More often that not this sequence works fine, I haven't noticed it at all in firefox but everytime I call it in ie6(the first time anyway) the users SESSION is wiped.

Comment: Which `Content-Type` did you go with in the end, and did you ever consider `application/vnd.ms-excel` since that's what you're supposedly generating?  (Fixing/choosing the right Content-Type might be enough to make IE behave...)

Comment: Sorry never saw your last comment(until I realised you needed to press another button), will give this a shot now. Thanks!

Comment: Newest header is up on the main post.

Comment: If you want more eye-balls to help you, you might want to clarify the main question with the following info: 1. Does the problem occur in all browsers?  2. Have you seen the problem yourself.  3. What exactly happens - XLS is downloaded and opens in Excel, and in the meantime your browser redirects to another URL?  What URL?  What's the PHP behind this other URL?  What do your Apache / IIS logs tell you is being requested? etc etc.

Comment: 1. Nope problem is ie6 specific
2. I have, it's repeatable in that when on ie6 after it starts-up it will definitely unset all session data.
3. On firefox/safari/non-crap browsers it stays on the same page and the file is served out as expected(no refreshes etc), on ie6 the file isn't served out, the page refreshes and the as it refreshes the SESSION data is unset and as a result the user will be forwarded to the login page.

The url is a fairly long list of arguments that is passed to an export to XLS function, that takes in GET vars executes a query and the results are stored in an xls file.

Comment: Here's the log file request being outputted.

 - - [04/Sep/2009:16:38:57 +0100] "GET /articles/exportToXls?hl=en&headers%5B__ref%5D=ARTICLE&headers%5B_modified%5D=Last+Modifed&headers%5Buser%5D=User&headers%5Btitle%5D=Title&headers%5Bdescription%5D=Description HTTP/1.1" 302 3982 "http://url/event_in/listing" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729)"

Comment: Do you know the generated `.xls` file-size so you can set a `Content-Length` header?  Try that.. then try other threads: http://forums.thedailywtf.com/forums/t/5134.aspx and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49284/file-downloads-in-ie6

Comment: Well it's variable but we have done basically the same thing with CSV and the same problem occurs, but with a generated file-length included, but I will try everything you've suggested and those links you've sent. After that I'll try xdebug and step through the code, but sinces it's IE specific, I'm not sure I'll find anything. Anyway, many thanks for all the help!